# How to get all objects with a date that fall in a specific month SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a simple SQLAlchemy model:

```
class Event(Base):
    """ The SQLAlchemy declarative model class for a Event object. """
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime)
    title = Column(Text)
```

How do I filter a SQLAlchemy query so that only events in a specific month are returned?

Comment: Do you need to filter the events in a specific month (example: June 2012, in which case @Tony's answer is good) or the events for June irrespective of the year?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should find all the events in June, 2012.

```
import datetime
import calendar

year = 2012
month = 6

num_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
start_date = datetime.date(year, month, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(year, month, num_days)

results = session.query(Event).filter(
    and_(Event.date >= start_date, Event.date <= end_date)).all()
```

Answer (score 21):

A very old question but a better answer is here:

```
from sqlalchemy import extract  

session.query(Event).filter(extract('month', Event.date)==7).all()
```

This returns all the records into a database events in July.

Comment: What if you want to extract both month and year?

Comment: Which db is used here because it does not seem to work for SQLite?

Answer (score 14):

I was wondering the same thing that Brady Huang was wondering. So to expand on @scottydelta's excellent answer:
You can just stack the filters on top of each other.
So if you want to extract every Event from July 2018 you should use

```
from sqlalchemy import extract  

session.query(Event).filter(extract('year', Event.date)==2018).filter(extract('month', Event.date)==7).all()
```